# How to link to non-markdown files in Jupyter book?

Tags: jupyterbook

How do I link to a non-markdown file in a Jupyter Book? I would expect that `[some text](relative-link)` works, but this is not the case.

For example, starting from a brand new Jupyter Book suppose in the source file I write in the generated `intro.md` file:

```
A link to [a markdown file](some-file.md)

A link to [a text file](other-file.txt).
```

Then I place `some-file.md` and `other-file.txt` next to `intro.md` and build the book. I get the error message:

```
intro.md:20: WARNING: 'myst' reference target not found: other-file.txt
```

Then `some-file.md` is processed and a link to `some-file.html` is generated (as expected), while the link to `other-file.txt` is not, and the file is not copied to `_build`.

If I place `other-file.txt` into the `_static` folder then it gets copied to `_build/html/_static`, but how do I refer to it? And in any case, it's silly that I should have put it in `_static`.

I would like to link to files that students can download (for instance a ZIP file or some source code that they should use). Surely this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

> ...the easiest way to do this is with the {download} role ...

as answered here https://github.com/executablebooks/meta/discussions/475#discussioncomment-1259744
by @choldgraf , i.e.,

```
A link to {Download}`a text file<./other-file.txt>`.
```

This also copies the corresponding files correctly.